# python function strftime seems to create wrong year

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have got the following code:

```
datetime.date(2019, 12, 30).strftime("%Y-%V")
```

which returns the string:

```
'2019-01'
```

where I would expect:

```
'2020-01'
```

seems to be wrong or is there a mistake I made?

Thanks!

Comment: `%Y` returns Year with century as a decimal number. why would you expected the following year?

Comment: You may want `%G` to pair your ISO week with the ISO year…?

Comment: thank you deceze, this is what I made wrong! works now..

Answer (score 2):

The year is going to be `2019` because when you are choosing `2019-12-30`, the year will be 2019 always. While the week will be the first week, and thus it will give `01` as the value of `%V`. The correct answer will be `2019-01`.